# How to get value from selected spinner item from json?

Tags: android, json, spinner

I am getting selected spinner value response like below -

```
{cCodeName=abc, nSerialNo=1}
```

How can i get "1" from "nSerialNo" in variable ?

Comment: i have posted some code here try it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to parse json like below:

```
String response={cCodeName=abc, nSerialNo=1};
JsonObject obj=new JsonObject(response);
String serialNo=obj.getString("nSerialNo");
```

in **serialNo** you get value of your spinner

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  JSONObject resObject = new JSONObject(new String(yourResponseString));
  int nSerialNo = resObject.getInt("nSerialNo");
```

This will get the `nSerialNo` Value